# JavaScript: "Uncaught SecurityError" when running JS-XSL demo locally

Tags: javascript, excel, parsing

(This question pertains to the JS-XSL demo found [**here**](http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xls/))

To briefly tell you what this demo is for; it takes a MS Excel file as input, parses the data, and outputs the data in text-only format. I downloaded the package (zip) and ran it locally, simply by opening the html file with Chrome.

The problem is, I just cannot seem to get over the following error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///C:/Users/David/Desktop/Xlsx%20Demo/xlsworker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.
```

And above error points to line 34 of the html file, which has the following code:

```
/* I changed the file path from './xlsworker.js' to 'xlsworker.js' */
var worker = new Worker('xlsworker.js');
```

There are only three files for this demo: the html file itself, and two javascript files, one is named `xls.js` and the other `xlsworker.js`. All three files are in the same directory and at the same level.

What's rather baffling to me is, I successfully ran this same demo about a couple months ago! I cannot imagine if I am doing anything differently now. Any insight?

Comment: You might need a server to run this.

Comment: @mpm - it must have been the reason; I got it running again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278883#c9

> You are basically prevented by Chromium to use workers on the file:// protocol, you have to host your files and access them through the http:// protocol.

You need a server (even something simple like http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

Comment: Thanks, Nirk. I'll check out the link.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the below is a superior answer, because it does not require running a web-server. It's extremely quick and simple.

(the downvote is explained in my Note 5, below)

I have tested and verified that this solution works with the demo linked by the asker, when run locally as described by the asker. Tested on Windows 10, Chrome Stable x64 48.0.2564.103 m.

A script is not allowed to access to your local file system in Chrome. If you'd like to test web workers locally, you have to open Chrome with a special flag.

On Windows, launch chrome with the flag:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

After that Chrome will be launched and you can test workers during this session.

Note1: if Chrome is already running when you run this command, the new instance of Chrome will *not* allow Workers to run-- you must first exit from Chrome (if necessary, use Windows Task Manager to ensure Chrome is not running).

Note 2: the source for this answer (link below) includes the --args flag on Windows, but i have not found the "args" to be necessary on Windows. In fact, i cannot find any documentation of the "args" flag anywhere-- not sure what it does. So i don't include it in the Windows command, above.*

Note 3: For those trying to do something similar on Chrome-Mac, or Windows-Firefox, the link below includes both, along with the Windows-Chrome solution above. But my solution described above is only the Windows-Chrome method.

http://js-workout.tompascall.com/web-workers-and-responsiveness/

Note 4: Be aware that this solution is not the same as running a web-server, but for your purpose it should be a completely adequate solution. Also, be aware that to browse the web with this chrome startup-switch enabled may compromise your local file-security, so it's advised to only use this method for your local file purpose, and disable it for web-browsing.*

Note 5: Google states that using startup flags "should only be used for temporary cases and may break in the future." Web search for chrome startup switches returns about 2,000 hits, so lots of people use them and blog about them. If your need is temporary, then this currently works great.*

Comment: Suggesting unsupported command line flags and `about:config` changes is not a good advise. `file://` URLs can exhibit all kinds of behavioral differences that normal `http://` or `https://` URLs do not and so the right way to go is to indeed use a local web server.

Comment: Also note that `--incognito` is not more secure in any way, it is not sandboxed any more than a regular Chrome instance. It simply does not persist cookies, history and local data. That is not "secure", it is only "private".

Comment: "Suggesting unsupported command line flags and about:config changes is not a good advise....incognito is not more secure"

I did not suggest any of the above.

Comment: `--allow-file-access-from-files` is an unsupported command line flag. `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` is an `about:config` entry. `--incognito` was about another post you submitted (that I rejected, for being out of context for that Google group), I admit. :)

Comment: "--allow-file-access-from-files is an unsupported command line flag."   **How do you know it's "unsupported"?    "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy is an about:config entry."  **I didn't say security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy, nor any other about:config. What's wrong with about:config anyway?  The asker is a programmer in a development environment, not an end-user.    "--incognito was about another post you submitted (that I rejected, for being out of context for that Google group), I admit."   **It's illegitimate to complain and downvote here based on something i posted someplace else.

Comment: Few command line flags are supported, like `--kiosk`. The rest are not supported. I do not have a reference for the supported ones, sorry. Regarding `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`, I copied it from your answer, "In Firefox you have to override"... I downvoted only because of those issues. The other comment was unrelated to the downvote.

Comment: i removed the Firefox solution, which is not really part of the answer anyway, because the user specified Chrome. It was included as a sidenote.  So your only remaining criticism is that *"allow-file-access-from-files is unsupported",*  but you did not provid any reference to back up your criticism.     *"I do not have a reference for the supported ones"*  Nobody's asking for a reference to supported flags. Please back up your claim that "allow-file-access-from-files is **unsupported**"  If you cannot, then no part of your downvote is legitimate.

Comment: Actually, command line flags are by default not supported, so you should back up your claim that it is supported. But here you go, see the third line here - https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags - "It is important to note that using these switches is not supported or recommended."

Comment: the full text is "It is important to note that using these switches is not supported or recommended. They should only be used for temporary cases and may break in the future." So, i believe this means the *reason* they are not recommended is because they may break in the future-- so don't use them for production systems. "Unsupported" means-- you can't get "support" for them, and they're not "guaranteed" to work. With that caveat, if the asker's need is temporary, then this currently works. In which case, it's an acceptable answer.

Comment: Question: About answers that include "unsupported", "unofficial", or other non-mainstream methods-- Is it StackOverflow policy that such methods not be suggested here? Or just your opinion?    It's my opinion that askers should be offered information about any potential solution, including potential risks (as i've done), and let the asker decide.   It sounds like you, PhistucK, do not want to grant the asker the information and the respect to make up their own mind.

Comment: Besides the insecure aspect of this solution, as I wrote, using `file://` URLs may cause behavioral differences that are specific to `file://` URLs and so I consider this the wrong answer. A simple local web server is definitely the way to go.

Comment: MAY cause? First, "may" means you do not know if it will or won't work, in this case. It remains for the Asker to try it. If it works, then it works, period. I suspect, if the Asker tries, then it will work. Many answers to many questions "may" not work, theoretically, but you don't know for a fact that it won't work. Secondly, please reference your claim that it may cause behavioral differences.

Comment: "I made a few claims and backed some of them"  --Interesting philosophy. First you post a comment here about some other website. Then you don't bother to back up ALL your claims, and for you that's "enough". Mainly, your downvote is purely philosophical, and not based on whether my solution actually works. I agree: you've done more than enough.

Comment: The Chromium website states: "switches should only be used for temporary cases and may break in the future." It DOESN'T say they shouldn't be used at all. The asker's usage is clearly "temporary".  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags?pli=1

Comment: The highly-regarded, widely-used, electron IDE relies on Chrome startup switches. http://imfly.github.io/electron-docs-gitbook/en/api/chrome-command-line-switches.html