# How to combine Chrome switches "incognito" and "allow-file-access-from-files"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, incognito-mode

The Chrome command switch `allow-file-access-from-files` allows local scripts to access other local script files (necessary for testing javascript Workers locally https://stackoverflow.com/a/35117877/209942).

That works for me.

Incognito runs a sandboxed Chrome. Also works.

Problem: the switches do not seem to be compatible. If i run

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --incognito
```

the `allow-file-access-from-files` flag does not take effect.

Any way to combine these flags? That would conveniently enable me to run a secure and non-secure instance of Chrome at the same time.

thx

**Update:** 
FYI, i may have uncovered a Chrome security bug:

allow-file-access-from-files works as expected in an incognito window if incognito is launched from the menu of a chrome running with the allow-file-access-from-files flag.

But if a normal chrome instance is running *(without* the allow-file-access-from-files flag), and then you execute `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --incognito` from a command-line, allow-file-access-from-files fails in the incognito instance.

It's contradictory for these features to work together when incognito is opened from the UI, but NOT work together when incognito is launched via command-line switch.

Answer (score 1):

(I reported the above as a bug to Chromium bug reporter. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582986
The report might not be public yet ).

My goal is to run two Chrome windows, one *without* allow-file-access-from-files, the other *with* allow-file-access-from-files. This is for development convenience.

Aside from incognito, I also tried using different profiles to achieve my goal-- doesn't work. Both profiles behave the same regarding allow-file-access-from-files-- the first profile launched will determine allow-file-access-from-files state for any subsequent profiles launched, regardless of startup flags.

I finally achieved my goal with the `user-data-dir` flag, to enable allow-file-access-from-files in one chrome instance, and not to another instance. (incognito and profiles are unnecessary).

It's used this way:

chrome.exe --user-data-dir=D:\MySeparateChromeFolder

Before using this flag, create the D:\MySeparateChromeFolder (change the name and location to whatever you want), but don't put anything in it. Then run the above command (with your desired name and location) from a command-window, the Run box, or make a new shortcut containing this command.

This will launch a completely independent Chrome -- more extreme than profiles. Chrome launched with this flag will have almost nothing in common with Chrome launched without this flag. It will have separate extensions, history, settings, bookmarks, etc, and, most important to this thread, other *startup flags used with this instance (such as allow-file-access-from-files) will be independent of other running chrome instances.*

Comment: I have tried this solution. It creates a completely new instance of chrome but allow-file-access-from-files switch is not working. Is it still working for you?

Comment: @UsamaMohsin I haven't tried it recently. I that switch might have been deprecated, but not sure.